# MySQL on windows iis not letting connection from outside local

Tags: mysql, windows, iis, server

I recently installed mySql on my windows server through iis, but when i try to connect via sql workbench to the server it wont let me in at all, ive tried everything from all the other stack overflow answers like adding bind-address = 0.0.0.0, opening the port and even disabling the firewall completely.

I'm correct in thinking the hostname is just the server ip right? am i missing something?

Comment: Can you connect from the server machine itself? If so check if SkipNetworking is un commented (it should be commented out).

Comment: yeah through the localhost, its commented out

Comment: if you telnet to the machine (ie- telnet serveraddress 3306) do you get a response. If yes, then networking is not the problem, just permissions within mysql. if no, then network problems are preventing access.